# How to measure the difference between the results of 2 T-tests?

Tags: research-design

For some context, I am currently trying to come up with the right type of research methodology for my masters in education and my thesis is basically comparing the difference between performances of students when using traditional pen and paper assessments and online formative assessments.

At the moment I have come up with a mixed sequential research design and I will explain what I’m doing below:

PHASE 1 (Part 1)
Pre-test and post-test using traditional pen and paper assessments and I will compare the scores with a T-test

PHASE 1 (Part 2)
Pre-test and post-test same as above but will instead be done using online assessment tools and scores will be compared with a T-test as well.

PHASE 2
Interviews of each student and to be analyzed with a thematic analysis to conclude their perspective towards the usage of online assessments.

My current issue at the moment is, how do I compare the difference between the students performances between the 2 sets of tests? Do I perform a T-test between the 2 T-tests? And if I do, is it still considered a sequential mixed method research design?

Apologies if anything might be unclear, writing at 7 am without any sleep but trying to figure this out.

Comment: I guess you will use a paired t test in Part 1: Same $n_1$ students take both pre and post test. You will have differences $d_{1i},$ for $i = 1, \dots, n_1.$ And you want to know whether the population difference $\delta_1$ differs from $0.$ // Similarly, a paired t test in Part 2: You will have differences $D_{2i},$ for $i = 1, \dots, n_2.$  Presumably the $n_2$ students here are different from the $n_1$ students in Part 1. // Then you could do a _two-sample_ t test to test $H_0: \delta_1 = \delta_2$ vs $H_1: \delta_1 \ne \delta_2.$ That would be a good plan, if variances in Parts 1&2 differ.

Comment: Hey @BruceET thank you for the reply really appreciate it. The students are actually the same group of students that are tested.What should I do in this case?

Comment: ... Especially if $n_1 = n_2$ and variances in Parts 1 & 2 are about the same, you might consider an ANOVA with factors A (before vs after) and B (pencil vs online), and factor C (students nested within levels of B). If that appeals to you, maybe one of us can explain details of the model and (depending on what software you will used) perhaps suggest specific procedures for analysis. // Do you know how large $n_1$ and $n_2$ will be, and approx sizes of the differences you might get?

Comment: That would simplify the ANOVA. However, I wonder if something students learn according to one of the methods would influence their performance on tests for the other method. At the very least, I would suggest half of students do 'pencil' first and a randomly chosen other half do 'online' first. // Students invariably forget some of what they learn, but you can hardly expect them to forget _everything_ from one part when being tested on the other.

Comment: I'm not sure if you caught what i said but yep n1 will be the same group as n2. What would I do in this case? Since you mentioned a two-sample t test would be a good idea if they were different groups, but what if they are the same group?

ANOVA sounds interesting, might provide me with a lot more data to work with when I write up my actual thesis but I'm so bad at this i'm worried i may just confuse myself.

Comment: As for your last comment, the way the students WILL be learning in different ways for both exams as the biggest difference between traditional and online assessments is the way they receive their feedback. So traditional = wait 1 week till we meet again and we review. Online = marks given straight away with feedback already individualized right under each question they get wrong and the next week they can do their post test immediately.

Comment: Also the sample group will be 15 students in total.